# Express - Refresh current page (routing troubles)

Tags: node.js, api, express, router, page-refresh

Having an issue refreshing the page upon changing routes.

I have something along the lines of

```
router.get('/home', function(req,res,next){
  if(switch){
    res.redirect('/page1');
  }
  if(!switch){
    res.redirect('/page2');
  }
})
```

I also have a router that handles a post request and alternates the boolean value of `switch`, and then redirects to the `/home` route using `res.redirect('/home')`.

My issue is that even after the boolean is switched, and router redirects, the new page does not display unless I manually refresh the page. Can anyone help, or point me in the right direction?

Edit: I'm also rendering the page using EJS templating. `res.render(...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910837/nodejs-expressjs-redirect-after-successful-insertion  relates to your question and the ans should help u

Comment: @RobertRowntree Hi Robert. I'm redirecting to the correct path (logging when a route is reached), however the client-side page doesn't update until I refresh the browser myself. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: Solved using socket.io package from npm. The issue was that the server rendered the page, however the client had no instruction to reload/refresh.